# Connection Pool and PooledConnection

Tags: java, database, connection, connection-pooling

I am currently learning about Connection Pooling concept. I went through the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#datasource_connection) in Oracle website that tells about Datasources and ConnectionPooling.

In the documentation it is mentioned:

> When the DataSource interface is implemented to work with a ConnectionPoolDataSource implementation, all of the connections produced by instances of that DataSource class will automatically be pooled connections.

The above statement is fine. To put it in simple words, a Connection Pool consists of Open Connections (PooledConnection) objects which can be accessed through the DataSource.getConnection() method.

It is mentioned in the PooledConnection interface documentation that the

> PooledConnection object represents a physical connection to a data source.When an application calls the method DataSource.getConnection, it gets back a Connection object. If connection pooling is being done, that Connection object is actually a handle to a PooledConnection object, which is a physical connection.

How does a PooledConnection object provide a java.sql.Connection object? I know there is a method `getConnection()` in the PooledConnection interface which provides the Connection object, but in the documentation it is mentioned as:

> The connection pool manager calls this method when an application has called the method DataSource.getConnection and there are **no PooledConnection objects** available in the Pool.

**So if there is a PooledConnection object that is already present in the Pool** then how is the Connection object obtained and how does PooledConnection provide the java.sql.Connection object when the Datasource.getConnection() is called and there is PooledConnection object present in the pool? How does a Connection object is actually a handle to a PooledConnection object? This is really confusing and documentations are not clear.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `DataSource.getConnection`, the datasource implementation knows how to talk to the connection pool manager, and asks it to provide the connection:

- If there is an existing (free) database connection in the pool, the pool manager returns it (and marks it as in-use).
- If there is no free connection, the pool manager creates the physical connection and adds it to the pool (as in-use) and returns it.

The relationship between the `Connection` and `PooledConnection` instances is (I think) driver dependent.  They could be represented by a single implementation class, or there could be distinct classes for the two concepts.

But your application code should not need to know this.  Indeed, ideally it should not depend on the driver implementation classes at all, because that would mean that your application is "coupled" with the driver code.

(The documents don't state this clearly because the spec writers were trying to avoid unnecessarily *constraining* driver implementations.  This is a good thing.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just was curious to know how the Connection object is obtained from the PooledConnection object. Since it is mentioed in the documentation that the getConnection in the PooledConnection will be called only when there is 'no PooledConnection objects available in the Pool.'. But if there is already a PooledConnection object present in the Pool, then how does DataSource get the Connection Object from this PooledConnection object. Can you please tell about this? The doubt is what method in the PooledConnection is called to get the java.sql.Connection object?

Comment: The MySQL, PostgreSQL, Derby and so on drivers are open source.  You can download the code, and read it for yourself to see what it actually does under the hood.  (I'm not keen to spend my time to satisfy your curiosity when you can do it for yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will check them.